# Angular 2 read json property undefined but other properties are fine

Tags: angular

I can read the "title" property from getHeroes() method doing `this.title`, if I do `console.log` I can see it, but not with "heroes" property, I have tried "this.heroes[0].id" "this.heroes" and everything is undefined. But If I do `console.log(this)` the JavaScript console show me all the properties.

What I'm doing wrong?

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;
  rows: Object[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
    //console.log("get heroes: "+this);
  }

  getRows(){
    var n = 3;
    for(var i=0; i<1;i++){
      console.log(this.title);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getHeroes` method is asynchronous so you need to move the `console.log` within the callback itself. Otherwise, the result isn't there yet:

```
this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => {
  this.heroes = heroes;
  console.log("get heroes: "+this);
});
```

If you use `console.log` after the call of the `getHeroes` method, you display something before setting the `heroes` property on the class.